# How to show content only when no empty value typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fallback

First i extend pages table in one of my own extensions for social share like `facebook` so, now i fetch this field value in the current page and that successive page, but if there is not field value in any of the pages then no icons should be display on frontend.

```
 10 = TEXT
 10 {
     data = levelfield:-1, field_facebook, slide
     override.field = field_facebook
     wrap = <li><a href="|" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Facebook" target="_blank"><span class="icon-facebook"></span></a></li>
 }
```

but currently i see only html if field is empty.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this.

```
 10 = TEXT
 10 {
     data = levelfield:-1, field_facebook, slide
     override.if.isFalse.field = field_facebook
     wrap = <li><a href="|" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Facebook" target="_blank"><span class="icon-facebook"></span></a></li>
     required = 1
 }
```

Comment: What should i do if i want to slide upto only same domain. for eg. if i have two domain then it must only slide to particular domain not upto root page(0).

Comment: There isn't a page with the uid 0 saved in the database. Option slide is only sliding up till the next page which has the flag `is_root` set, so it should work even if the domain's rootpage is in a subfolder.